# Overflow Error in Flutter when keyboard open

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am designing a login page it **overflowed** when I click on any text form field it open **keyboard** and through overflow warning like this see attached image.
I also want a Raised button icon should be on the right side of the button.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new AssetImage('assets/login_page_bg_1.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.55), BlendMode.dstATop))),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 42.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset('assets/logo.png',
                            width: 250.0, height: 200.21),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //form filed goes here
                        Text('Login As User',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 35.0)),
                        TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'you@example.com',
                              labelText: 'Email Address',
                            ),
                        new Container(
                          // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: RaisedButton.icon(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(251, 188, 74, 1),
                            label: Text('LOGIN'),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.send,
                                size: 10.0, color: Colors.black),
                            onPressed: () {
                              this.submit();
                            }, ),)],),),)],)],),),);
```

[Intital state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHLFE.png)

[Error/overflowed State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6suX0.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is happening because when the keyboard comes on screen, the height of the canvas to draw decreases. One solution is to wrap your root container inside SingleChildScrollView like this :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.loose,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                        image: new AssetImage('assets/login_page_bg_1.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.55), BlendMode.dstATop)
                            )
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 42,),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Center(
                      child:
                        Image.asset('assets/logo.png',
                            width: 250.0, height: 200.21),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                        //form filed goes here
                        Text('Login As User',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 35.0)),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'you@example.com',
                        labelText: 'Email Address',
                      )
                    ),
                      new Container(
                        // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: RaisedButton.icon(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(251, 188, 74, 1),
                          label: Text('LOGIN'),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.send,
                              size: 10.0, color: Colors.black),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //this.submit();
                          }, ),)],)),
                  SizedBox(height: 40,)
            ],)],),));
```

It will make your screen scrollable when the height of the content gets more than the available height of the viewport.

Comment: it through an exception
I/flutter ( 2894):  EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
I/flutter ( 2894): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():

Comment: give the container a fixed width and height.

Comment: on all container?
because by giving width and height to the root container cause same problem

Comment: give the root container width and height as `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

Comment: I edited my answer...now refactored the code instead of just looking at it and guessing the problem. Your code was too inefficient but I tried to keep most of it as it is.

Comment: This surely can't be the accepted answer because it allows the view to scroll way too to high to the top.Bad design

Comment: Its tool old that I don't even remember what I did there.

Comment: Maybe it's me but there's no SingleChildScrollView in this code

Comment: As you can see from comments and edit history, it was changed after further discussions. Forgot to change the description.

Answer (score 55):

Set following property to `false`

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
  ... 
)
```

---

If you're having issues with overflow error, use `SingleChildScrollView` with it.

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // set it to false
  body: SingleChildScrollView(child: YourBody()),
)
```

PS: If you like to scroll your widget when the keyboard opens, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70612950/6618622)

Comment: I had to set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` for the second example above - so that `SingleChildScrollView ` scrolling kicked in when the keyboard appears. Whereas setting the value to `false` means the keyboard overlays the UI and obscures things, and the scrolling didn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 8):

A much simpler solution ([source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13339#issuecomment-400373394)) seems to be just setting the `Scaffold` property `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` to `false`.
This works great with me:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        appBar: AppBar(...),
        body: ...
```

Comment: FYI: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is flagged as deprecated and it's recommended to use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` instead.

Answer (score 6):

1. Add `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,` and `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,`
   to your Scaffold widget.
2. Wrap your code with a `Container`, set the `Container`'s parameters `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,` and `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,`. Then wrap your `Container` with a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: For some mystical reason, this was the only solution that worked to me. Scaffold widget was basically ignoring the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` option. No idea why. Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

you should make the scaffold's floating widgets should size themselves to avoid the onscreen keyboard using :

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
  ... 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An even easier version is to just wrap the offending container with a ListView widget.  It makes the screen scrollable and is simple to implement.  You can use multiple children with this widget.

```
Scaffold(  
   body: ListView(
     children: <Widget> [
       Container(
       ),
       TextView(
       ),
       Column(
       ),
     ],
   ),
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` and using `body: ListView()` works as well. This enables you to scroll the page when you open the keyboard.