# Keyboard hide textfield when editing textfield( flutter)

Tags: flutter, textfield, keyboard-events

While editing my textfield the keyboard hide half the screen. I want to make the screen push up with the keyboard so I can see all the field. How do I do it?

[image: Before tap to a textfield]
[image: After tap to a textfield]

Here my widget form, I have already tried SingleScrollView but the problem is my view turned all white

```
class SignUpFormState extends State<_SignUpForm> {
  final _signUpFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<LoginModel>(
        builder: (context, loginModel, child) => Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: Card(
                  child: Form(
                      key: _signUpFormKey,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container( height: 16.0,),
                            Text(),
                            Spacer(flex: 3, ),
                            Padding(),
                            Padding(),
                            Padding(),
                            Padding(),
                            Spacer( flex: 4,),
                            Row(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use SingleChildScrollView() widget like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60521914/12932518

Comment: add your code too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overflow Error in Flutter when keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312583/overflow-error-in-flutter-when-keyboard-open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SingleChildView likes this.

```
class SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //If you use Scaffold in parent widget, use Container instead of Scaffold.
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column([Your Login Form Widget])
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If I used SingleChildScrollView widget, all my content turned white. I don't know why.
Have you ever faced with this problem ??

Comment: For that problem, I need more information.
Could you upload your Column widget code please.

Comment: I user Spacers in my column widget. I think those are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scaffold` as the root and add 
`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,`
just before the end of `scaffold` bracket. You'll be good to go.

example:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        .....


      ),


 resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, //this line here

    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Scaffold` widget as the root of the screen. Problem will be solved.

For example :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView(  // or Column
      // contents
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Without Scaffold, this screen is not visible. means, he is already using Scaffold. 

He need to wrap body in SingleChildScrollView()

Comment: I meant root of this screen.

Comment: @AR , See, the problem is - TextField goes under keyboard. Using Scaffold, can solve this. I hope you'll reconsider your downvote.

Comment: Screen designed by the user is static right now, that screen width and height will be different in different mobile. So he needed flexibility to scroll if contents are more than current screen size. 
Issue on Keyboard opening, anything you are entering your textfield should appear on screen. So if it isn't appearing it will gives error.
by using SingleChildScrollView(), it will gives you flexibility to scroll up a little so textfield will viewable.

@AR you have to consider your downvote